# How to automatically transfer data from one cell in one worksheet to another cell in another worksheet in the same workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

When I select a particular cell in the 1st column the data from the cells in the 2nd and 3rd column of the same row as the selected cell should get transferred to a two particular cells in another worksheet. How do I do it?

For example consider two worksheets `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`
[Sheet1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI40C.jpg) 
[image] 
[Sheet2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlHM7.jpg)
[image]

When I select cell `A3` as selected in `Sheet2` Image, the data in cell `B3` should be automatically transferred to the cell `E6` in `Sheet1` and data in cell `C3` in `Sheet2` to cell `B2` in `Sheet1`.

Please remember I might select any cell in column `A` in `Sheet2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert below code into data source sheet (Sheet2 on your screenshot) module:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
' When selection on the worksheet is changed we check
' that only one cell is selected (not multicell range)
' and this cell is in column 1 (column A)
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    ' If one cell in column A selected, we copy the value 
    ' from a cell right to selected (row is the same, column is greater by 1)
    ' to the left-up cell of solid destination range on the destination sheet
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value
    ' and the same for a cell where row is the same and column is greater by 2
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E6").Value = Target.Offset(0, 2).Value
End If
End Sub
```